# Optimization of a Data Tree for Video Game Objects

Tags: java, data-structures, arraylist, game-engine

So I'm currently working on Data Structures for my java game, and I'm using ArrayLists. However, I've found that having these structures causes severe speed problems. I store my game objects in storage objects called Zones.

In pseudo code:

```
object Zone{

   ArrayList ObjList;

Do Task (Draw/Phys/Logic){

   for(i=0 to ObjList.length){

        ObjList[i].doTask;
   }

AddObject(obj){
     ObjList.add(obj)
}
```

And I store them using a simple nested for loop:

```
 for(i=0 to number of storage classes){
    for(j=0 to number of objects per storage class){
         objectClass Obj = new Object;
         StorageClass.add(Obj);
    }
  overall ArrayList.add(StorageClass);
 }
```

And that's basically it, I've turned off the collision detection because I know it's not done with the objects themselves and only by the storage class. However, I can render 800 objects in 1 storage class at 60fps, but should I attempt to run 10 storage classes with 80 objects each I get barely 8 fps. Is there any data structuring I can use to improve my speed, or is this the only way it can be done?

Comment: The problem with array lists is that they have a huge 'overhead' nedded to obtain count of the items etc. So if you have 800 objects in one array list, you only need that extra stuff once, but if you have 10 lists you need taht stuff 10 times, so that might be what causes your performance problems.

Comment: Is there an alternative that I could use that won't have such an overhead?

Comment: I think you will have to decide between the flexibility of an Array List and the better performance of an normal Array. But I'm sure there is a solution for this issue since you are not the only one developing games. Sadly i don't know any.

Comment: @Gumbo what are you talking about when you say overhead to obtain a count of the items? ArrayList maintains a size variable.

Comment: @user1071777 maybe I din't express myself clear enough, maybe the meta data of the array list isn't the problem, but managing the items in the list is still very inefficient compared to an array since ArrayList uses arrays internally. So if you call `remove(index)` for example the wohle array needs to be reorganized. So array list is still pretty ineffective.

Comment: @Gumbo True, Peter hasn't really given much detail to what he's doing.